Error HttpFileFailedToRead when copying data from http to Blob storage in Microsoft Fabric pipeline
I have developed several pipelines in ADF and now I was testing the functionality in Microsoft Fabric, however, I faced the first challenge with a simple copy data activity. Here is my use case:
The European Central Bank publishes on a daily basis in xml here: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml
I need to get that data and put it in a blob storage. A simple Copy Data activity.
In ADF it is working smoothly:


However, in Fabric, replicating the same, I get the following error when running the pipeline with just this Copy Data activity:
ErrorCode=HttpFileFailedToRead,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to read data from http server. Check the error from http server：The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.,Source=System,'



Partly solved. I had as file formats binary for both the source and destination, because XML cannot be selected in the destination. I changed the file format in both the source (XML instead of binary) and the destination (JSON instead of XML) and the copy data activity suceeded, but now, of course, I have a JSON and not a XML (I can work with that but find it annoying that the same activity differs so much from ADF to Fabric).

Partly solved. I had as file formats binary for both the source and destination, because XML cannot be selected in the destination. I changed the file format in both the source (XML instead of binary) and the destination (JSON instead of XML) and the copy data activity suceeded, but now, of course, I have a JSON and not a XML (I can work with that but find it annoying that the same activity differs so much from ADF to Fabric).
